# Joining nougat hotspot

Tags: android, android-networking, android-7.0-nougat, hotspot

My app has 2 buttons, one to create a hotspot, another one to join a hotspot.
The flow is :

I create a hotspot on one of the devices and then try to join it with other device (through my app).

The problem is that sometimes i can not join the hotspot if it was created by a Nougat device, it gets stuck on "Obtaining IP Address".

This is the code that i use to join the network :

```
  List<WifiConfiguration> list = wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();
  for( WifiConfiguration i : list ) {
   if(i.SSID != null && i.SSID.equals("\"" + networkSSID + "\"")) {
     wifiManager.disconnect();
     wifiManager.enableNetwork(i.networkId, true);
     wifiManager.reconnect();               

     break;
  }           
}
```

The code to create the hotspot is the usual... by reflection with the method setWifiApConfiguration().

Is it an Android bug ? Or it is due to my code?

EDIT : It works on Android 7.0, but doesn't work on Android 7.1.1. I guess it might be a bug, because the hotspot will be created, be won't be marked as active.

Comment: are you able to resolve this ?

Comment: hello, not yet :(

Comment: is there any alternative method to enable hotspot 7.1.1 ?